# Browser not reading decoded html_entity_decode text

Tags: php, html, mysql, htmlspecialchars

I have a Textarea where I encode inputted text in a MySQL database.

When decoded it returns this:

```
<div>5</div><div>54545</div><div><br></div><div>dfs</div><div>df&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;333</div><div>s</div><div>f</div><div>sdfff</div><div>f</div><div>ff sdf ff sdf&nbsp; &nbsp; sdf&nbsp; df sdfd sdf sdf</div><div>f</div><div>f</div><div>f</div><div>ff</div><div>d&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 3333333333333</div><div>fsdf</div>
```

Code for upload is just the value from a Textarea encoded using `htmlspecialchars()`

Decoding is :

```
$content = mysqli_fetch_assoc(find_about_text()); <br>
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($content["about_text"]);
```

i've tried using parameters in the decode process of course

For some reason it works when i echo it into a textarea

Source code looks like this:

```
&lt;div&gt;5&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;54545&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;dfs&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;df&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;333&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;s&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;sdfff&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;ff sdf ff sdf&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; sdf&amp;nbsp; df sdfd sdf sdf&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;ff&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;d&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; 3333333333333&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;fsdf&lt;/div&gt;
```

when using utf8_decode() it returns this:

```
&lt;div&gt;5&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;54545&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;dfs&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;df&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;333&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;s&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;sdfff&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;ff sdf ff sdf&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; sdf&amp;nbsp; df sdfd sdf sdf&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;f&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;ff&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;d&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; 3333333333333&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;fsdf&lt;/div&gt;
```

Comment: _Browser not reading decoded html_entity_decode text_ Please explin clearly what that means. Doe sit show something different? Does it show nothing?

Comment: Have you looked at the "page source" to see what is actually getting sent to the browser

Comment: @Riggsfolly edited with source code text

Comment: Html encoding should only be done when displaying, not before storing in the db.

Comment: What happens when you try to decode it twice -- literally call the function on the same string twice? ...no, I'm not joking.   What if you encode it, insert it in the db once, then you update the values and on the update you double encoded it?  <--just guessing now.

Comment: @mickmackusa It just keep adding &amp; to everything

Comment: @Riggsfolly Not incoding before upload and then decoding when using it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

User @mickmackusa added to not encode before uploading to database, and that was the problem.

Simply upload and then decode using html_entity_decode() works